# Java Generics - Type parameter `K` is not within its bound; should implement X

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the java docs on generics, specifically [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) on bounded types and am lost. Here is a simple version of my code, for context I generically want a compare-able key, one with an `Integer` and another abstract class with a `Date`, here is just the base abstract class and the integer implementation:

Abstract class:

`public abstract class A<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends TreeMap<K, V>`

Integer Abstract class:

`public abstract class B<K extends Integer, V> extends A<K,V>`

The error I get is in the type reference of the second class at the part `extends A<K,V>`. Specifically, my IDE is underlying the K and says `Type parameter 'K' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<K>'`

I am confused on this because in the definition of `Integer`, it implements a `Comparable<Integer>`, is that not enough to satisfy this? Moreover, when I try to do the following, `public abstract class B<K extends Integer & Comparable<K>, V> extends A<K,V>`, that does not work either.

Am I misunderstanding something with generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error occurs because although `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`, a subclass of `Date` might not implement `Comparable<SubclassOfDate>`, so the compiler complains.

You can fix this by changing `A`'s declaration to use a wildcard:

```
public abstract class A<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> extends TreeMap<K, V>
```

However, you probably intended to declare `B` like this:

```
public abstract class B<V> extends A<Integer,V> {

}
```

`Integer` is `final`, no other class can inherit it. So `B` does not have to be generic on `K`.

As for the class with `Date` as the key, you probably want to do it like this as well:

```
public abstract class C<V> extends A<Date,V> {

}
```

But since `Date` is not `final`, you *could* make a generic parameter `K extends Date`:

```
public abstract class C<K extends Date, V> extends A<K,V> {

}
```

Comment: `The compiler error occurs because although Date implements Comparable<Date>, a subclass of Date might not implement Comparable<SubclassOfDate>, so the compiler complains.`

This explains it, thanks so much! It is interesting though that for a final class like Integer the compiler is still not smart enough to figure that out

Answer (score 4):

Since `Integer` is a final class, the correct definition of `B` would be:

```
public abstract class B<V> extends A<Integer,V> {

}
```

You don't need the `K` type parameter.

Comment: Or
`public abstract class B<K extends Integer, V> extends A<Integer, V>`